# Division Algebras as Algebraic Groups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

If I'm given a division algebra D with Z(D)=F, then how can I view D<sup>x</sup> as an algebraic group defined over F?  I'd like to see first how D<sup>x</sup> can be given the structure of a variety defined over F, and then to see how the group law on D<sup>x</sup> is defined over F.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Choose an F-basis of D. The multiplication is described by certain quadratic functions, with respect to this basis; D* is given by the nonvanishing of a polynomial function (the norm). 
So the multiplication can be understood as defining an algebraic group structure on the complement of a hypersurface in an affine space.

Comment: And for the record, this is the exact same way that you show GL_n is an algebraic group.

Comment: Is it part of the general theory of division algebras that the norm is a polynomial function?

Comment: @Joel: After base change to a matrix ring, the norm becomes the determinant.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose D splits over a finite extension K/F, i.e., the tensor product of D with K over F is isomorphic to M<sub>n</sub>(K).  Then D<sup>x</sup> is the group of F-points of an algebraic group over F that exists as a direct factor (along with all other F-division algebras that split over K, and GL<sub>n,F</sub>) in the restriction of scalars Res<sup>K</sup><sub>F</sub> GL<sub>n,K</sub>.

I don't know an explicit presentation in general (say, starting from a Brauer class), although if K/F is a cyclic Galois extension, there is a nice cyclic algebra construction.  I think more details can be found in Serre's *Local Fields* and Cornell-Silverman.